# Apache Regex doesn't return first result

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL:

```
http://somedomain.com/aa/search/search.php
```

I want it to return 2 selections, that of "aa" and that of "search/search.php".

With the help of Regex Coach, I have made the following regular expression which targets these two just fine:

```
/([a-z]{2})/(.*)
```

However, when I use them in my htaccess file, the rewrite just doesn't happen:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /([a-z]{2})/(.*) /$2?var=$1
```

Can someone point this regex newbie in the right direction?

edit:

By "doesn't happen", I mean that following the URL: somedomain.com/aa/search.php gives me 

"/aa/search.php not found" 
rather than 
"/search.php?var=aa not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on where you define the rule. Your syntax is correct for server (global) config files. If you use `.htaccess` files, the server will strip the path upto the place where the file is located from the URL. Try

```
([a-z]{2})/(.*)
```

(i.e. without the first slash)

Comment: I am indeed using htaccess files... This solved my issue (in addition to adding ^ to the front)